# What does "block all network load requests" mean?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am looking for ways to speed up WebView loading and I came across [WebSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkLoads%28boolean%29) which is described very briefly in the documentation:

> Tell the WebView to block all network load requests.

But it's unclear to me what "*all network load requests*" mean.

Does it block loading images, like [setBlockNetworkImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkImage%28boolean%29) does?

Does it block other things? (if so, what does it block?)

Comment: I would just try using it and see what happens. Run ACID or Kongregate to see if it blocks JavaScript or Flash or everything.

Comment: @notverycreative That's a very creative answer, and I *am* about to start experimenting with this, but I am looking to understand the **terminology** as well. I have a feeling that "network load requests" has special meaning among web experts.  (I am not such an expert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this code sample](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/trunk/src/com/fsck/k9/view/MessageWebView.java?r=3135) it means "preventing WebView from loading **external** resources over the **network**".

I interpret this as allowing to load resources locally (cache, memory) but not over the network, not even a URL that you explicitly specify.

So, just as you observed, it will block **everything**, including images.

Comment: If it blocks everything, why is it recommended as a replacement to `setBlockNetworkImage()`? Can you provide a use example?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used that particular setting but without any further context I would think that it means the WebView .load methods.

```
WebView.loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding);
WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl);
WebView.loadUrl(String url);
WebView.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders);
```

Comment: +1 for the 1st attempt to answer this question. I just tried setting WebSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(**true**) and NOTHING is being loaded from the URL specified, not even HTML! Which means that you are probably right, but then why would Google recommend using this method instead of setBlockNetworkImage()?

Answer (score 1):

It is used to prevent the WebView from loading other pages.  So if you need to display a page but not allow any links clicked within the loaded page, then use this.

Load the page, then set this flag to true for this to work.

I think!

Comment: +1 for the 2nd attempt to answer this question. It's interesting to see that no one is really sure about an answer. What does this say about the documentation? LOL